# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.stream'

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to run an akka stream application, but I am getting an exception:

```
No configuration setting found for key 'akka.stream'
```

the relevant code snippet is:

```
ConfigFactory.load()
implicit val system = ActorSystem("svc")
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
```

I try both command lines:

```
java -jar ./myService.jar -Dconfig.resource=/opt/myservice/conf/application.conf
java -jar ./myService.jar -Dconfig.file=/opt/myService/conf/application.conf
```

my application.conf file:

```
akka {
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  actor {
}

stream {

# Default materializer settings
materializer {
  max-input-buffer-size = 16
  dispatcher = ""
  subscription-timeout {
    mode = cancel
    timeout = 5s
  }

  output-burst-limit = 1000
  auto-fusing = on
  max-fixed-buffer-size = 1000000000
  sync-processing-limit = 1000
}

blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.stream.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"

default-blocking-io-dispatcher {
  type = "Dispatcher"
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1

  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 16
  }
}
}
}
```

exception details:

```
No configuration setting found for key 'akka.stream'
    at 
 com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:145)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:172)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:258)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:264)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:37)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializerSettings$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:248)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$$anonfun$1.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$$anonfun$1.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at com.Listener$.main(Listener.scala:41)
    at com.Listener.main(Listener.scala)
```

can you assist?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load config from a file, you should use:

`-Dconfig.file=/opt/myService/conf/application.conf`

Doc link: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior

Comment: It is strange, because the `akka.stream` config path should at least be defined in the `reference.conf` that is included with the akka-stream jar. Is `myService.jar` a fat jar? How do you load the configuration?

Comment: if i run it with no arguments, i get the same error. it is a fat jar indeed

Comment: added info in message

Comment: How are you building the fat jar? You need to ensure the various `reference.conf` resources don't overwrite each other when you package it otherwise missing config keys can result.